# Getting IP Address of NIC

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there any official way to get the IP Address of NIC ?

I found a way with the use of getIfAddrs. But it seems that it is not mentioned in SDK. So is the risk (banned by AppStore) high ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding local ip address in the iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527439/finding-local-ip-address-in-the-iphone)

Comment: See also [Find IP address in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361345/find-ip-address-in-iphone) and [How do I query the iPhone's current IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260484/how-do-i-query-the-iphones-current-ip-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking to the use of `getIfAddrs(3)`, as a BSD system call, it's not a private API, so its use should not be prohibited in any way.

Answer (score 0):

never tried before, but i kept reference of this function to retrieve ip address. it might work

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309927273/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone