# How can I get city name without current location(lat-long) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, latitude-longitude, google-geocoder

I have a GPS class which returns lat, long. And I'm trying to get the city name or address from that coordinates with geocoder. It works well.

But, is it possible to get city name or anything without geocoder or (lat-long)?

Comment: hey @iphonic Rohit wants without using DB if there is any services (JSON) available than that he wants to use B'coz you say some DB is up to 30 MB than it will not the proper solution.

Comment: MaciekWroclaw Don't use Geocoder

Comment: @iphonic Ya thanks for trying to help him

Comment: @MaciekWrocław OP don't want to use the GeoCoder. Please check the question

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799864/how-to-get-the-users-current-city-name-without-using-the-core-location-service may you get help from it.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA What do you mean by geocoder? I thought OP doesn't want to go online, there is always google api for you to achieve this, you can get any kind of data by that json/xml. Check link [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20maps%20api%20get%20city%20name%20from%20coordinates)

Comment: @iphonic still don't get my point friend we don't want to pass any lat-long to service means any services which takes lat-long we don't want it's our challanging task so that's y we posting here.

Comment: @iphonic If you have any other idea to find location without lat-long than will be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have completed task use this api:

> http://ip-api.com/json

This will give you your current location from your IP address very simply just call this JSON and you got whatever you required.

Comment: @rohit-suvagiyaThanks for this solution, quite simple and easy